# will same collections of document return TopN docs using TopScoreCollector when segment is changed from time to time

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I try to migrate my program from lucene based search to Elasticsearch and I put same collection of documents into lucene and Elasticsearch to do compare test. in ES, I used only one shard and change mapping for each filed's similarity to classic. but still I got different results when I use public TopDocs search(Query query, int n) to fetch N top score docs. when N is small, the results lucene based and ES has diff while when N is bigger and bigger, the diff ration is reduce. so I'd like to know what cause this diff and how can I achieve no diff.

below is my assumption to the problem:

since TopScoreCollector return topN docs while score is calculated based on segment.
so if N documents divide into different number of segments, the score will be influenced since tf/idf will changed.
this is my overall understanding and I'd like to know if my understanding is right or wrong.

Comment: What do mean by "while score is calculated based on segment" ? I think you are wrong here, see https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

Comment: @EricLavault in the page you give, there is idf(t) stands for Inverse Document Frequency. while idf(t) is calculated based on segment wide, so the different document collection will have different ids(t). that's exactly what I want to say that the score is calculated based on segment. since all the other part of variables in Lucene Practical Scoring Function won't changed anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you here.. but of course : different collections = different idf(t), now what do you want to achieve ? You want to query several collections and be able to normalize scores in each ?

Comment: @EricLavault I comment below since the comment is too long

Comment: Do you mean for each index? An index is made up of several segments (which is a detail about how Lucene stores its files) - no scoring is dependent upon the segments as far as I know. But yes, for an index the score calculated will be based on documents on the current node (in Solr, at least - I'm not familiar with ES). Also be aware that Lucene now uses BM25 (and applies certain score normalization), so if you're migrating from an older version, the similarity algorithms will not be the same.

Comment: @MatsLindh I put the collection of documents into 1 index in lucene based search app and ES. if what u said, "no scoring is dependent upon the segments as far as I know", then what caused the diff?

Comment: Different scoring algorithms, different normalization, different number of deleted documents in the index (remember that deleted documents still count against scoring) - there's probably a way to get Lucene to return how it calculated its score, which Solr allows at least - ES too probably.

Comment: @MatsLindh let's forget about delete since since there is no delete in my case. how to guarantee lucene/ES set the same scoring algorithms, normalization?

Comment: I'm not sure what use you'd get out of the absolute numbers being identical - it's the relationship and sorting between them that's important.